# Web apps are not seen at sub sites

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, web-part

I am trying to add an announcement section to every site/sub site in our site collection. It will be the same announcement page so everyone sees the same announcements. I can go to the site where I made the announcements (our home page) and edit page > insert web part and the announcement list is there, but when I go to a sub site or other site within the collection, it is not in the web parts. I can make web pages and all the home page web apps are there including my announcement list.

I have exported the web part and imported it into the web parts gallery and it is there but it does not work. I have also used designer to do it (instructions at link). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TntwRm78b_4 This video is of SharePoint 2010 and I have 2013. Does anyone know how to do this?

Error message
Cannot import this Web Part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer to this I found one. Instructions are at the link.

http://zepeda-mcmillan.blogspot.ca/2011/08/cross-site-web-xsltlistviewwebpart.html

Just find the GUID for the page and then place the GUID in place of all the 0's from your export. It worked on my sub sites.

Answer (score 0):

We used a content search web part which allows you to search the entire web app and show contents. You just need to add a content search web part and configure the search to only search your list which is I'm assuming at the root level site collection.

Comment: I have also heard you could add the URL under Content Query in Content Rollup. For example:  Lists/Announcements. But i have SharePoint Foundation 2013 and I do not have those options. I have put the URL in other Web parts to check and it brings up the page, but I do not have the right web parts. Thanks for responding.